# Fenced code block inside another fenced code block

Tags: markdown

I'm trying to write article about Markdown syntax, and to write it, I use Markdown.

So, my document looks like this:

````
Example of markdown code:

```
foo

```
fenced code block (fail)
```

bar
```

lalala...
````

And this breaks the parser. Screenshot taked from [Commonmark dingus](http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/), but is also rendered in some another parsers I tried, namely Showdown and MultiMarkdown.

(Maybe such issues fixed in non-javascript parsers, like Kramdown? I doesn't tested)

[image]

How it may be fixed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I couldn't find it documented but you can increase the amount of backticks in [*commonmark.js dingus*](http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/) and [*GitHub Flavored Markdown*](https://github.github.com/gfm/). Your example could be fixed like this:

``````
Example of markdown code:

`````
foo

```
fenced code block (fail)
```

bar
`````

lalala...
``````

Be aware that it might not work on other parsers (like Showdown). However, some parsers do not support *fanced code* at all. Another possibility is to not use fenced code. You could write

````
Example of markdown code:

    foo

    ```
    fenced code block (fail)
    ```

    bar

lalala...
````